# Android Shape Line

Tags: android, shapes

I have the following code:

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line">
   <stroke android:width="1dp"/>
   <size android:height="1dp" />
   <solid  android:color="#FFF"/>
   </shape>


   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background ="@drawable/line"/>
```

I have two questions:

1. Why the line is black instead white? I have tried putting it inside a ImageView but the result is the same.
2. How can i set the opacity of the shape?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1) In order to set the color of the line, you need to define [`android:color`](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#shape_stroke) on the `<stroke>`.  The [`<solid>`](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#shape_solid) element is for the background.

2) You can set the opacity of the shape by using [color values with an alpha layer](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#colorvals), aka #ARGB.  In your case, maybe #7FFF.

Comment: @Vaiden Android supports 4-digit ARGB. In that case, it will be interpreted as #77FFFFFF.

Answer (score 22):

The simplest example of the line for 2 density pixels with black color.
Just save the xml in drawable folder: res/drawable/shape_black_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke 
    android:width="1dp" 
    android:color="#000000" />
<size android:height="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Use LinearLayout and background to show the line.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/divider">
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Wouldn't it be less memory consuming if we used `<View>`instead of LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes u can use it . As everyclass is extened from view

Comment: Can you explain the difference in code between yours and the OP's? That's not obvious at first sight

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way can be like this:

1) Add a View where you want have a line.

2) set `android:background` to a hex value that you can set both color and opacity.

For example:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:background="#77f27123"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```